# States of matter / kinetic energies / intermolecular forces

Tags: energy, kinetic-theory

My question is about the things that determine the state of matter
I have been searching for a while now and some sites say that:

> "both kinetic energy and intermolecular forces determine the state of matter"

But some say:

> "since it is because of the intermolecular force that for example in solids the kinetic energy of molecules is less so the states of matter are only determined by the intermolecular forces".

Are any of these even correct?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your confusion arise because of the mixing of force, $F$, potential energy, $U$, and kinetic energy $E_{\rm K}$.
There is a connection for a conservative force in that $F=-\frac {dU}{dx}$.

Consider a molecule sitting in a *potential well* at position $D$ as shown below in a **very simplified** diagram with the graphs looking sinusoidal only for ease of my drawing then.

[image]

The molecule would be in position $D$ if it had no kinetic energy.
Give the molecule some kinetic energy by increasing the temperature and the molecule will start to oscillate between positions $C$ and $E$.
So the molecule is oscillating about position $D$ and you have the solid state.
In terms of the (intermolecular) force you will note that as the molecule moves towards position $C$ the force is in a direction towards $D$ and when it moves towards position $E$ the force is again in a direction towards $D$.
Thus the molecule is constrained by the intermolecular forces to stay around position $D$.

If a molecule has kinetic energy greater than $U_{\rm B}-U_{\rm D}$ it can *escape* from the region about position $D$ and there is now the possibility of the transition to the much more complex liquid state in which molecules can change their nearest neighbours and usually the average separation of the molecules increases.

Given enough kinetic energy the separation of the molecules is such that the intermolecular forces between molecules are much less significant and the molecules move more *freely* between collisions.
Here I have mixed energy and force ideas because it possibly reads easier than *given enough kinetic energy the separation of the molecules is such that potential energy of two molecules is insignificant except during collisions.

Comment: Thank you so much 